# 19:04: can't open a vnc port

Tags: iptables, firewall, ufw

At a complete dead end here. Got a Centos background, new to Ubuntu. I've followed various tutorials to get a tigervnc server running, and set up the firewall as follows:

```
$ sudo ufw allow 5901  # etc
```

`nmap localhost` tells me that `vnc-1` is running, listening on 5901. However, if I do a scan from another box:

```
# nmap -sT -p 5901 ip4.new.ubuntu.box
```

It tells me that 5901 is actually *closed*. `nmap` correctly identifies that 22 is open.

I've saved the iptables rules, and they look fine - ports 22 and 5900-5903 are all ACCEPT, and are treated identically. However, I'm not sure that I set this up from `ufw` - I think I only allow'ed port 5901, as shown above, and the tigervnc installation might have set the other rules.

However, `iptables` isn't even running. `systemctl iptables status` can't find the service, but `systemctl ufw status` reports that `ufw` is running.

I've tried turing off `ufw` with `ufw disable`. From what I've read, this opens all ports, but it doesn't. A Centos box on the network is still reporting that port 22 is open, but all other ports are closed.

So, what on earth is going on? How is port 22 open even with `ufw disable`? Why isn't `iptables` running? How exactly does the out-of-the-box firewall work on 19.04? Thanks.

Comment: What *interface* is vnc-1 listening on? is it perhaps not listening on the external interface?

Comment: @steeldriver: you're right, thx - `netstat -ano` shows `127.0.0.1:5901`. It's working if I start vncserver as `vncserver -localhost no`, which is the difference from Centos and/or earlier tigervnc versions. If you want to do an answer I'll accept it.